# Apache Spark - how to see how many nodes are being used during a job run?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Scala Spark 2.4 and want to know the usage of the queue.

How to display how many nodes from a big cluster (100+ nodes) are being utilized for any particular job that is running?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the Spark UI?

Comment: Yes, can be accessed.

Comment: Also - there seems to be Dynamic resource allocation. Spark also has a feature called Dynamic resource allocation. It gives spark application a feature to dynamically scale the set of cluster resources allocated to your application up and down based on the workload. How to know how many nodes were being used total?